# PL/SQL procedure does not run and shows system error on click

Tags: html, plsql, toad

I have a procedure which has several cursors as well as a html text field and button on a web form which should be running the procedure on click. This textfield and button also has javascript message which shows user input. However on click of the button i receive system error and i'm sure its not calling the procedure. i have a lot of code so therefore i will not post it as of yet but if required i can do. this is being run on the toad for oracle.

```
    PROCEDURE P_UNSUSPEND_SEARCH(bannerid IN INTEGER DEFAULT NULL)
IS
BEGIN 
<< PL/SQL Blocks >>

END; 

--
-- html button 
htp.p ('<form action="BANINST1.UAP.P_UNSUSPEND_SEARCH">');
        htp.p ('<input type="text" method="post" name="bannerid" id="bannerid" placeholder="e.g. 000123456" maxlength="9" 
               autocomplete="off" required>');  
        htp.br;
        htp.p (' <input type="button" onclick="confirmMsg()" value="Submit">');
```

--
-- javascript

```
htp.p ('<script type="text/javascript">
                        function confirmMsg() {
                                var field1 = document.getElementById("bannerid").value;
                                alert(field1+" has been unsuspended");
                                }   
                   </script>');
```

Comment: You must tell what errors you are facing. Is it oracle side ie Java side how anyone will know by just looking at the piece of code.

Comment: @XING I've somehow managed to fix the error. the error was just a system error. i believe it happened because my procedure couldn't connect with the database.

Comment: Good to hear that bt please make sure that whenever you post a question, relevant details should always be there.